# Sqlalchemy Db relationship on list of foreign keys

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table designed as

```
class A:
   name = db.column(db.String())
   table_b_ids = db.column(db.String())
   table_b_records = db.relationship()


class B:
   name = db.column(db.String())
```

`table_b_ids` holds comma separated id which is primary key of table B.
I want create relationship `table_b_records` in such a way that on fetching data from table A, `table_b_records` will be list of records from B for all the IDs in
`table_b_ids`.

The reason behind storing foreign keys as string is that in my actual model there are two foreign keys pointing to same table like below

```
class A:
   name = db.column(db.String())
   export = db.column(db.Int, db.ForeignKey("b_table"))
   import = db.column(db.Int, db.ForeignKey("b_table"))
```

Now table_a can have multiple export and multiple import. For this I must keep 4th table which I didn't find right in my case. Hence kept like

```
class A:
   name = db.column(db.String())
   export = db.column(db.String())
   import = db.column(db.String())
```

Comment: Do you mean that `table_b_ids` is a comma-separated string of foreign key IDs?

Comment: Is this a strict one-to-many between B and A, or can a single B be claimed by more than one A?

Comment: Yes table_b_ids are comma separated string of foreign key IDs. This is many to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have a column full of comma-separated IDs is neither here nor there. You can't use that directly to create the relationship.

The right way to create a many-to-many relationship in an RDBMS is using a mapping table. You will need to split out the IDs from this column into the mapping table to create the mappings. (If you are adding new data, just skip populating that column in the first place and instantiate the mapping rows while creating the various A and B rows from the source, wherever that is).

Here is the discussion of [many-to-many relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) in the SQLAlchemy docs. For posterity, this is the current first example of a parent and child many-to-many in the SQLA docs:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


# note for a Core table, we use the sqlalchemy.Column construct,
# not sqlalchemy.orm.mapped_column
association_table = Table(
    "association_table",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("left_id", ForeignKey("left_table.id")),
    Column("right_id", ForeignKey("right_table.id")),
)


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "left_table"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    children: Mapped[List[Child]] = relationship(secondary=association_table)


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "right_table"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
```

---

**Update:** The reason to create a mapping table for a many-to-many relationship is that you will then be able to query using SQL JOIN. With the ids stored as a string like this, SQL won't see the relationship, and so you won't be able to use the power of SQL when selecting and doing other DB actions. It will also certainly be slower because SQL won't be able to optimize queries using the relationship; you might actually have to do everything in Python, transferring all the data over first and then sorting/filtering. For any size of query, that will not be performant.

It sounds like your hesitation with using a mapping table here is that you don't want 4 tables. I'd say the right way to think about a many-to-many table like this is less "mapping A to B" and more "formalizing a particular relationship between A and B". Since there are multiple relationships, then it makes sense that there would be multiple tables.

You could add another column to the mapping table to distinguish the relationship in question ("is this an import or an export?"). However, that's really just another way of describing the same thing, and mapping tables with extra columns are a bit of a hassle in SQLA. So my recommendation is that you reconcile yourself to having one mapping table per relationship, even if the two tables being related happen to be the same as another relationship.

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect explanation for your question. I was trying to achieve this by primaryjoin="func.find_in_set" but was not getting the result hence asked here

Comment: Thanks for adding more to the question. I've updated my answer.